# Unable to use string.substr(x, y) multiple times on the same string with c++?

Tags: c++, string, command, substr

I'm working on a command line interface. 
The user enter a commands such as

This would add a "song" with the `-s` flag

```
add -s TITLE ARTIST
```

This would add an "album" with a `-a` flag

```
add -a TITLE ARTIST
```

There are different flags and different commands like *delete* as well.

I've done this to evaluate the commands and flag, however I'm having trouble getting the rest of the string. The user input is taken in as an array of char, which I convert into a string.

```
  if (inputString.substr(0, 3) == "add"){
    if (inputString.substr(4, 5) == "-s"){
      cout << "TEST: ADD SONGS" << endl;
      //PROBLEM IS THIS LINE
      cout << inputString.substr(6, MAX_LENGTH) << endl;
    }
```

Whenever I get the command + action flag, I'd like to run a new function using the rest of the string to actually add the information into the database.

There is no problem when I type`add -s` The program knows I want to add a song from evaluating the first characters. However if I type in more such as "`add -s "Sorry" "Justin Bieber"` The program doesn't even acknowledge that the add -s flag was run.

Can someone explain why this is and how I can change it? Stuck on it for a while now.

Comment: As a note, doing this yourself is going to be a whole world of hurt. Have you considered using a library like [Getopt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt)? It's practically universal in C.

Comment: You could improve your question a lot with a [mcve]. What have you observed in your debugger?

Comment: I would consider using a string splitting algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string

Answer (score 1):

```
if (inputString.substr(4, 5) == "-s"){
```

The second parameter to `substr()` is the character count. This extracts (up to) 5 characters from the string, starting at offset 4.

> However if I type in more such as "add -s "Sorry" "Justin

Ok, so using my fingers to count off to offset 4, that is, indeed, the '-' character. Then, extracting five characters starting at that position arrives at the following string:

```
-s "S
```

I count that as five characters. That's what the `substr()` returns. Comparing this for equality with the string "-s" obviously fails.

You should take this as a convenient opportunity to learn some debugging skills. Had you added something like this:

```
std::cout << inputString.substr(4, 5) << std::endl;
```

Right before the second `if` statement, I'm confident you would've figured this out all by yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I always thought the second parameter to substr was the second position.